# What should I do to replace :hover to something clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a full-width accordion and I did something like this for:

```css
.page {
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0.4;
    -webkit-flex: 0.4;
    -ms-flex: 0.4;
    flex: 0.4;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-flex 500ms ease-out;
    transition: -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
    transition: -ms-flex 500ms ease-out;
    transition: flex 500ms ease-out;
    padding: 20px;
}

.content:hover {
  -webkit-box-flex: 50;
    -webkit-flex: 50;
    -ms-flex: 50;
    flex: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content one">Content</div>
  <div class="content two">New</div>
  <div class="content three">Div</div>
  <div class="content four">Tag</div>
  <div class="content five">Here</div>
</div>
```

and there is no way that I can replace that hover thing into click.
I tried to use jquery but failed.
I also wanted the Content div to be the largest page at the start so I tried to use input radio stuff, but I failed that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I'm understanding what you are asking, but It seems that you want to make some css rules work when the content is clicked.

What you could do is to add an event like:

```
 $(".content").click(function(){
    $(".content").toggleClass("when-clicked");
 });
```

Then you should have something like this in your styling:

```
.content.when-clicked{
    -webkit-box-flex: 50;
    -webkit-flex: 50;
    -ms-flex: 50;
    flex: 50;
 }
```

That should do the trick